# Any great cyberpunk campaigns with atmoshphere like the first disc of Final Fantasy 7?

Tags: game-recommendation, campaign

I was thinking I might want to run a campaign with an atmosphere like the Midgard part of FF7, but I'm really bad at thinking up stuff like that, so I'm looking for something pre-made.

I'm not set on any one system or setting, but I love long, epic campaigns that take the characters from level zero to MAX ;)

Thanks for your advice!

EDIT: For those who haven't played Final Fantasy 7, the first couple of hours play in a high-tech city ruled by a large corporation which is killing the planet. The player controls a small resistance group (eco-terrorists, really) operating from the slums *beneath the city*. The city was literally built *on top of* the slums (which weren't slums back then, obviously).
The atmosphere is very much like Blade Runner, though maybe even more dilapidated and more oppressive.

Comment: Welcome to rpg.se! Please take a look at the [tour], it's a useful introduction to the site. Unfortunately we've discovered the Stack Exchange format (being significantly different from a traditional online forum) doesn't handle game recommendations very well. We've got [a list](http://meta.rpg.stackexchange.com/q/5449/4398) of places that might be better suited to help with this sort of thing, including (once you've got 20+ rep) the [chat].

Answer (score -4):

The Eberron setting for the 3rd and 4th edition of Dungeons & Dragons might actually be a good candidate, especially the main city Sharn.
While it's a world with elves, dwarves, orcs, and dragons, the culture and society is heavily inspired by early 20th century Europe and the different races have all been given new roles. (Except dwarves, they are still the same as always.)

Sharn is a huge industrial city of scyscrapers with lots of factories and other dirty and smelly stuff at the bottom, while at the very top the rich and powerful live in fancy tower castles.

Comment: Good idea for a setting indeed. I already have the Eberron 3.5 book and been meaning to play something there. Slightly off-topic, though, since I'm looking for an *adventuring campaign*, not a setting :)

Comment: I totally don't understand the downvotes on this.